# Concatenating a number contained in a string to another string

Tags: string, cocoa, casting

My Mac app reads a device connected to a serial port. The read returns 4 characters, one at a time as ';' '0' '4' '5' for example (always a semicolon followed by 3 integers.) I need to concatenate them into one string for display on a label. My attempt to use accumString = [accumString stringByAppendingString:(string)]; results in a crash. I think it's because the digits aren't strings, but I don't know what they are since they come in in a string.

No luck with stringWithFormat either.

My questions are:
1) How can I determine what type the digits are?
2) How can I simulate the input for testing? I don't have direct access to that hardware.
3) How to get them all put together for display.

A portion of the console log:

```
2014-07-14 18:09:04.354 LRotor[357:707] Building return: ;
2014-07-14 18:09:04.356 LRotor[357:707] Building return: ;0
2014-07-14 18:09:04.358 LRotor[357:707] -[__NSMallocBlock__ stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000005a250
2014-07-14 18:09:04.359 LRotor[357:707] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-07-14 18:09:04.360 LRotor[357:707] -[__NSMallocBlock__ stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000005a250
2014-07-14 18:09:04.360 LRotor[357:707] (

    - (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (rotorSelected == 2)
    {
      if ([string length] < 4)
        {
            NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
            if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
            {
                accumString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%??", string];

            }
            else
            {
                accumString = [accumString stringByAppendingString:(string)];
            }
            NSLog(@"Building return: %@", accumString);
        }
        if ([accumString length] == 4)
        {
            string = accumString;
        }
```

Revised code that solved the problem.

```
- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received: %@", string);
    if (rotorSelected == 2)
    {
        if ([string length] < 4)
        {
          if (!accumString)
          {
            accumString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
          }
          [self processPartialString:string];
        }
    }
}

- (void)processPartialString:(NSString *)iString
{
    NSString *tmp = @"";
    NSInteger x;    

    NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    if ([iString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        x = [iString integerValue];
        tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long) x];
        [accumString appendString:(tmp)];
        NSLog(@"Building return: %@", accumString);
    }
    else
    {
        [accumString appendString:(iString)];
        NSLog(@"Building return: %@", accumString);
    }
    if ([accumString length] > 3)
    {
        iString = [accumString substringFromIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"Showing label: %@", iString);
        [labelCurrHdg setStringValue:iString];
        [accumString setString:@""];
    }
}

- (void)startTimer
{
    hdgTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(printHdg)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
}

- (void)printHdg
{
    NSInteger currH = [labelCurrHdg intValue];
    NSInteger wantedH = [hdgVal intValue];
    NSData *dataToSend;
    NSString *str;
    if (currH > wantedH - 3 && currH  < wantedH + 3)
    {
        [hdgTimer invalidate];
        hdgTimer = nil;
        [labelCurrHdg setStringValue:hdgVal];
        [labelCurrHdg needsDisplay];
        return;
    }

  switch(rotorSelected)
    {
        case 2:
            str = @"AI1;";
            break;
        case 7:
            str = @"C\r";
            break;
        default:
            str = @"";
            break;
    }
    if ([str length] >0)
    {
        dataToSend = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that `accumString` doesn't point to an `NSMutableString`; it seems to be pointing to garbage. You need to make sure it's set correctly.

Comment: Can you show more code? We need to see where `accumString` is defined in addition to the rest of this method. But `accumString` doesnt need to be `NSMutableString` for this implementation as @JoshCaswell says since you aren't mutating it. And I do see some code issues unrelated to the exception (using %?? instead of %@ for string formatting).

Comment: Oh, yup, you're right @AlexZielenski; I read that too fast and incorrectly saw `[accumString appendString:(string)];` The pointer still doesn't contain a valid object, regardless of its type, however.

Comment: @Alex Zielenski - accumString is being added to 4 times, so I think that's mutating it, yes? It's not clear in the code I showed. accumString is now a mutable string, and seems to be created and released OK. The new code is being tested in Latvia now. More when the results come in.

Comment: The original accumString instance is not being mutated. You are creating new instances and setting the pointer.